# Javascript - Run function *after* another function runs on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using scrollsaver.js (http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver) to maintain scroll positions of elements on postback. There are instances where I wish to reset scroll position though, and I am having trouble doing so.

Paging through a list, I wish to scroll to the top on each page change. I do this by registering a call to resetGridScroll (below) in the paging handler.

scrollsaver.js ties to the page load event. When I do the same, my function runs before scrollsaver.js loads positions. Is there a way to force mine to run after page load?

```
function resetGridScroll() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div.items").animate({ scrollTop: 0, easing: 'swing', queue: false }, 15000);
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** I ended up clearing the cookie scrollsaver.js sets to store scroll positions. It gets cleared before the script loads so all positions are reset. Not elegant, but workable.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to load an external js script and execute code afer it you could use [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and put the code in the callback:

```
$.getScript("scrollsaver.js", function(){
    //code to execute after the script has loaded here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the function that calls the `resetGridScroll()` within :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 //here
});
```

Not your function being called for example :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   resetGridScroll();
});


function resetGridScroll() {
    $("div.items").scrollType(0);
    $("div.items").animate({ scrollTop: 0, easing: 'swing', queue: false }, 15000);
}
```

Comment: That still runs before scrollsaver.js does its thing. Also, I'm unclear as to the difference between .ready(innerFunction()) and outerFunction(.ready(innerFunction())). I'm using outerFunction to call the reset only when I need it.

Comment: the [ready() function in jQuery is actually an event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) - its an event thats triggered the DOM has loaded - you cannot put it within a function and call it the way you were..... if your script is running too early you need to attach it to an even that the other script triggers ? if there is one ? or call the method that init's the other script first then call this method ... if you include some more details in your question it might help - ie how you call the other function

Comment: Perhaps there is a callback available for onload in scrollsaver that you can use. Or you can always write one in.

Comment: @Matt Maybe you can call a callback after the script has loaded